# Node JS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, arrays, json

I get the TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined. I don't know what is wrong with the below code:

```
app.post("/entershop", (request, response)=> {         

let username = request.body.uname;
let psw = request.body.psw; 

let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('mapping.json');
let rootdata = JSON.parse(rawdata);
let isvalid = false;
let shops = rootdata["shops"];

shops.forEach(function(shop) {
var password = shop[username][0];
if(password === psw) 
    {
       console.log('successful login');

    }
else 
    {
       console.log('login unsuccessful');
    }
  });
 });
```

The error is displayed as below in the web page:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
at app.post (/home/ubuntu/TheRandomShops/index_test.js:33:15)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/TheRandomShops/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/home/ubuntu/TheRandomShops/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/home/ubuntu/TheRandomShops/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/TheRandomShops/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /home/ubuntu/TheRandomShops/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/home/ubuntu/TheRandomShops/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/home/ubuntu/TheRandomShops/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at serveStatic (/home/ubuntu/TheRandomShops/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:75:16)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/TheRandomShops/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5
```

And the `mapping.json` looks like below:

```
{
"owners":[
            {"name":"Bala", "id":"1", "psw":"bala"},
            {"name":"Rohit", "id":"2", "psw":"Rohit"}
           ],
"employees":[
            {"name":"Krithi", "owners":"Bala", "psw":"Krithi"},
            {"name":"Kumar", "owners":"Rohit", "psw":"Kumar"}
           ]
 }
```

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is no `shops` property on the data you'ev parsed. There are `owners` and `employees` properties, but no `shops`. So `rootdata["shops"]` is `undefined`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('mapping.json');
let rootdata = JSON.parse(rawdata); these two will take take time so rest of the code is exicuted before these two are completed

Comment: @SfaheequeTP readFileSync is... synchronous.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will resolve your issue

```
app.post("/entershop", (request, response)=> {         

let username = request.body.uname;
let psw = request.body.psw; 

let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('mapping.json');
let rootdata = JSON.parse(rawdata);
let isvalid = false;
let shops = rootdata["shops"]||[];

shops.forEach(function(shop) {
var password = shop[username][0];
if(password === psw) 
    {
       console.log('successful login');

    }
else 
    {
       console.log('login unsuccessful');
    }
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

rootdata is empty because there is nothing called shop in your data